# php static variable in another file?

Tags: javascript, php, static-variables

I have a static variable defined in some file called `lastitems.php`.

`lastitems.php` gets called every 5 seconds by a javascript function `update_items()`.

But because `lastitems.php` is totally another file, then the static variable is redefined every time the file gets opened.

Is there a way to avoid redefining (re-initiating) the variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lastitems.php

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['var'] = 'something';
```

Comment: How about when i call `lastitems.php` again and again? doesn't `$_SESSION['var']` gets reassigned with the same 'something' ?

Comment: @AlaaM. Yes, what value do you what to assign and what logic determines what value is assigned?  Edit your post and add some more info.

Comment: Eventually i used `$_SESSION['var'] = 'something';` in the `index` file (which gets opened firstly). And then asked about `$_SESSION['var']` in `lastitems.php`. It worked, thanks.